# Hadoop - Eclipse asking which java application to use on Map-Reduce job

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I have create a map-reduce job - without any error.
I am trying to run it from eclipse localy - but eclipse asking me to choose a java application to choose - I have no idea what to choose.

If that helps my project is  [here](http://pastebin.com/W5dPxF9Q)

[image]

1. Please if you could also explain to me why does it happen ?
2. Please help me and tell me what to choose ?

Comment: Are you using maven or added directly jar files in eclipse to execute map reduce code ?

Comment: Directly added external jars

Comment: have to run, not getting your solution. You can hide & try like remove all the jars and add jars from the hadoop/share/hadoop directory. for a try you add all the jars and run your program. I think it will work.